# Download file with native JavaScript from a url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application where I am getting list of events and displaying them in a list. I want to have a button when I click on a specific event, it adds the user as an attendee. I had it that I display a button afterwards to show "download invitation link" but the requirement changed to download the file automatically once the user clicks the first registration link.

I am checking resources on the internet and found 2 options, the first is with `URL.createObjectURL()` but I don't currently have an object, I have a url of the file returned from the request. The second object I found was the `browser.downloads.download` but I am not sure if this would support internet explorer 11.

I thought about using the link I already have to download the file, and call it from another button, but I don't know if that's possible in React.

How can I solve this?

Comment: No guarantee you can download without setting the proper headers. I would use PHP's [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#example-2965) for that. Just make sure your link goes to the `.php` page.

Comment: I am not using PHP.. I am just using a front-end app with React + TypeScript

Comment: Most Servers are PHP ready. You shouldn't have to do anything *(except alterations)* but save that file and put it into a folder. You should also know that if the file is not one that the Client's Browser recognizes, it should attempt to download automatically.

Comment: I know that the server the website is hosted on isn't using PHP.. it's made with asp.net mvc.. but I don't have access to it. I am working on a pure front-end page, that is retrieving data from that asp.net site. I would wanna have a solution purely front-end.

Comment: What is the extension of the file you wish the Client to download?

Comment: .ics file. Outlook invitation.

Comment: You should just do like `<a href='yourFile.ics'>Click Me</a>`. Unless the Browser recognizes the file extension it will ask the Client if they want to download or run the file or do it automatically from Browser settings. For your own safety, don't ever just hit that run button, or click on the downloaded file unless you trust the file. If it's not an executable, and you don't have a program set up to run the file then it's not an issue, from a security standpoint.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, works fine.. but I want to do it from code, as I am registering the user in the button click, adding the user as an attendee, then I want to download the file. So actually the button has an onclick handler.

Comment: Then you don't even need that link on your page, just do like: `const ics = document.createElement('a'); ics.href = 'yourFile.ics'; document.getElementById('yourButtonId').onclick = ()=>{ ics.click() };`

Comment: That did the trick!